# div run through loop and perform disable and enable button with same classes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My loop runs 3 times.

Inside the loop `div` is run and its 3 time run.

When in box 1 `div` I checked checkbox and if it is checked a button is enabled, otherwise the button is disabled.

That works but its run on loop so its 3 time save `div` with same classes.

If I check first `div` like box 1 checkbox then only enable button of box 1 `div` other `div` not affected.

If I check box 3 checkbox then only disable this button not other.

How is this possible?

**My code**

```js
$(document).ready(function (){

   $('body').on('click' , '.currentcheck' , function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("checked");

      if ($(".currentcheck.checked").length>0) {
        $('.btn_disable').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $('.btn_disable').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Your Self</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-state=1"/>
</head>
<body>     
 <form>
   <div class="box">
  <div class="element_checkbox">
      <p>box 1</p>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
   <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
   <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
   <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
            <button class="btn_disable" disabled>next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="element_checkbox">
      <p>box 2</p>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
   <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
   <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
   <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
   <button class="btn_disable" disabled>next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="element_checkbox">
      <p>box 3</p>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
   <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
   <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
   <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
   <button class="btn_disable" disabled>next</button>
  </div>
   </div>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you are reinventing radio button groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').on('click', '.currentcheck', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    //get the parent that encapsulates the checkboxes related to the one that was clicked
    var $parent = $this.closest('.element_checkbox');
    
    $this.toggleClass("checked");

    //only look at the checkboxes in the parent
    //only change the btn in the parent
    if ($parent.find(".currentcheck.checked").length > 0) {
      $parent.find('.btn_disable').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $parent.find('.btn_disable').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test Your Self</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-state=1" />
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="element_checkbox">
        <p>box 1</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
        <button class="btn_disable" disabled>next</button>
      </div>
      <div class="element_checkbox">
        <p>box 2</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
        <button class="btn_disable" disabled>next</button>
      </div>
      <div class="element_checkbox">
        <p>box 3</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chec1" class="currentcheck">
        <button class="btn_disable" disabled>next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```